# Generate file names list using cmd / powershell and adding coma after each file name?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to generate all file names in a folder which I am able to do using **cd** command accessing my folder location and then using **dir /b > files.txt**.  This works just fine but I also would like to be able to add a comma after each file name and I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: do you want to know the syntax in PowerShell or cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell ouput on one line:

```
(gci).Name -join(',')
```

Several lines

```
gci|%{$_.Name+","}
```

Cmd line several lines

```
for %A in (*) do @Echo %~nx,
```

On one line

```
Set "result="
for %A in (*) do @if not defined result (@set result=%A) else (call Set "result=%result%,%A")
Echo %result%
```

In a batch file change %A to %%A

Comment: As it is not clear what exactly you were after, I hoped one of the versions would fit - I'm still curious ;-)

Comment: I work with a lot of assets so have folder of 100s plus assets and in code I have to reference each asset so wanted something nifty to use in visual studio code terminal to generate all names of all assets instead writing whole script for that or typing them manually out;) I am still not super familiar with powershell but your answer was very helpful thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out :

```
$names=ls | select Name
foreach($name in $names)
{
$result+=$name.Name + ","
}
$result.remove($result.length -1)| out-file Files.txt
```

Comment: Also This solution worked pretty good too...Thanks for taking time and helping out

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell 3.0+ you could use `Get-ChildItem -Name` with the `-join` operator:

```
$FileList = (Get-ChildItem -Name) -join ','
```

In PowerShell 2.0 the same can be achieved with:

```
$FileNames = Get-ChildItem |%{$_.Name}
$FileList = [string]::Join(',',$FileNames)
```